# How to submit date to server in utc using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I am using angular form that is sending date to server.
I have issue with submiting date, when submitted it send date -60 min (affected due to daylight savings).
My app is local to UK only.

Form code:

```
<input type="text" name="date" data-ng-model="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required>
```

Submitting data:

```
var data={
  date: new Date($scope.date),
};

dataSvc.save(data).$promise.then(
function(response){
  //code
});
```

In my debug tools I can see the date beeing send:

- For date: 12/08/2014
- I will receive on server: 2014/08/11 23:00:00

My working solution but not the one I am happy with:

```
var data={
      date: new Date($scope.date + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()), // in my case is -60
    };

dataSvc.save(data).$promise.then(
function(response){
//code
});
```

Now I have found better solution but still not ideal is:

```
    function createDateAsUtc(date) {
        return new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()));
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want your timezone offset to be "+0000"? The `getTimezoneOffset` function returns the timezone offset of the server, which may not be UTC.